# Articles about model of eye movements and trajectories

Tags: reference-request, eye-movement

I need to work with data from an eye tracker. I have raw data about eye coordinates. I need to reconstruct trajectories of eye movements. Since I know modern science has several methods for this task, I already googled for them, but I don't know which ones are serious and authority works.

Comment: Welcome to CogSci! I edited your question a bit to reflect what I think you intended to write down. In case the edit misrepresents your original question, feel free to roll back to the original.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you already found and where it is exactly you are stuck? We expect you to [do a minimum level of research prior to asking a question](http://meta.cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/66/21). Apparently you already googled a bit, update your question to reflect what you learned from that, and what you don't understand. As it stands now answering the question would constitute summing up all related literature which would not only be near impossible, but also won't help you out that much.

Comment: As i know for representation of trajectories we can use markov chain model,frequency approach or other probabalistic models. But i can't find general source of information about representation of trajectories

Comment: What kind of eyetracker is the data from?  What if any software do you have available? What kind of questions are you trying to answer?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you may have looked up previously, but here are a couple of referenced articles that may be of help to you:
["Identifying Fixations and Saccades in
Eye-Tracking Protocols"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.68.2459&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (Salvucci and Goldberg, 2000), from their abstract:

> In this paper we propose a taxonomy of fixation identification
>   algorithms that classifies algorithms in terms of how they
>   utilize spatial and temporal information in eye-tracking
>   protocols.

In terms of Human-computer interaction:

["Commentary on Section 4. Eye tracking in human-computer interaction and
usability research: Ready to deliver the promises."](http://www.ergoestudio.com/descargas/eye-tracking_usability_research.pdf) (Jacob and Karn), this article makes reference to several more specific references.

Comment: This material is very useful! Thank you!

Comment: @user3560 I am glad these are of use to you - if you need anymore, let us know.